# JS express connecting to a mongoose db

Tags: javascript, node.js, database, mongodb, express

So I am fairly new to the express framework and to the mongoose database, I mostly used relational databases. I want to create a database with the following script, I have the mongod.exe running and listening on localhost:27017, and this works as I can connect to it via mongo.exe and via http. However when I try to run the script with node nameOfTheScript I keep getting

> (node:1000) DeprecationWarning: current URL string parser is deprecated, and will be removed in a future ver
>   sion. To use the new parser, pass option { useNewUrlParser: true } to MongoClient.connect.
>   FINAL ERR: ValidationError: genre: Path `genre` is required.

my script:

```js
var async = require('async');
var Book = require('./models/book');
var Author = require('./models/author');
var Genre = require('./models/genre');
var BookInstance = require('./models/bookinstance');


var mongoose = require('mongoose');
mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017/');

mongoose.Promise = global.Promise;
var db = mongoose.connection;
mongoose.connection.on('error', console.error.bind(console, 'MongoDB connection error:'));


var authors = []
var genres = []
var books = []
var bookinstances = []

function authorCreate(first_name, family_name, d_birth, d_death, cb) {
    authordetail = {first_name:first_name , family_name: family_name }
    if (d_birth != false) authordetail.date_of_birth = d_birth
    if (d_death != false) authordetail.date_of_death = d_death

    var author = new Author(authordetail);

    author.save(function (err) {
        if (err) {
            cb(err, null)
            return
        }
        console.log('New Author: ' + author);
        authors.push(author)
        cb(null, author)
    }  );
}

function genreCreate(name, cb) {
    var genre = new Genre({ name: name });

    genre.save(function (err) {
        if (err) {
            cb(err, null);
            return;
        }
        console.log('New Genre: ' + genre);
        genres.push(genre)
        cb(null, genre);
    }   );
}

function bookCreate(title, summary, isbn, author, genre, cb) {
    bookdetail = {
        title: title,
        summary: summary,
        author: author,
        isbn: isbn
    }
    if (genre != false) bookdetail.genre = genre

    var book = new Book(bookdetail);
    book.save(function (err) {
        if (err) {
            cb(err, null)
            return
        }
        console.log('New Book: ' + book);
        books.push(book)
        cb(null, book)
    }  );
}


function bookInstanceCreate(book, imprint, due_back, status, cb) {
    bookinstancedetail = {
        book: book,
        imprint: imprint
    }
    if (due_back != false) bookinstancedetail.due_back = due_back
    if (status != false) bookinstancedetail.status = status

    var bookinstance = new BookInstance(bookinstancedetail);
    bookinstance.save(function (err) {
        if (err) {
            console.log('ERROR CREATING BookInstance: ' + bookinstance);
            cb(err, null)
            return
        }
        console.log('New BookInstance: ' + bookinstance);
        bookinstances.push(bookinstance)
        cb(null, book)
    }  );
}


function createGenreAuthors(cb) {
    async.parallel([
            function(callback) {
                authorCreate('Patrick', 'Rothfuss', '1973-06-06', false, callback);
            },
            function(callback) {
                authorCreate('Ben', 'Bova', '1932-11-8', false, callback);
            },
            function(callback) {
                authorCreate('Isaac', 'Asimov', '1920-01-02', '1992-04-06', callback);
            },
            function(callback) {
                authorCreate('Bob', 'Billings', false, false, callback);
            },
            function(callback) {
                authorCreate('Jim', 'Jones', '1971-12-16', false, callback);
            },
            function(callback) {
                genreCreate("Fantasy", callback);
            },
            function(callback) {
                genreCreate("Science Fiction", callback);
            },
            function(callback) {
                genreCreate("French Poetry", callback);
            },
        ],
        // optional callback
        cb);
}


function createBooks(cb) {
    async.parallel([
            function(callback) {
                bookCreate('The Name of the Wind (The Kingkiller Chronicle, #1)', 'I have stolen princesses back from sleeping barrow kings. I burned down the town of Trebon. I have spent the night with Felurian and left with both my sanity and my life. I was expelled from the University at a younger age than most people are allowed in. I tread paths by moonlight that others fear to speak of during day. I have talked to Gods, loved women, and written songs that make the minstrels weep.', '9781473211896', authors[0], [genres[0],], callback);
            },
            function(callback) {
                bookCreate("The Wise Man's Fear (The Kingkiller Chronicle, #2)", 'Picking up the tale of Kvothe Kingkiller once again, we follow him into exile, into political intrigue, courtship, adventure, love and magic... and further along the path that has turned Kvothe, the mightiest magician of his age, a legend in his own time, into Kote, the unassuming pub landlord.', '9788401352836', authors[0], [genres[0],], callback);
            },
            function(callback) {
                bookCreate("The Slow Regard of Silent Things (Kingkiller Chronicle)", 'Deep below the University, there is a dark place. Few people know of it: a broken web of ancient passageways and abandoned rooms. A young woman lives there, tucked among the sprawling tunnels of the Underthing, snug in the heart of this forgotten place.', '9780756411336', authors[0], [genres[0],], callback);
            },
            function(callback) {
                bookCreate("Apes and Angels", "Humankind headed out to the stars not for conquest, nor exploration, nor even for curiosity. Humans went to the stars in a desperate crusade to save intelligent life wherever they found it. A wave of death is spreading through the Milky Way galaxy, an expanding sphere of lethal gamma ...", '9780765379528', authors[1], [genres[1],], callback);
            },
            function(callback) {
                bookCreate("Death Wave","In Ben Bova's previous novel New Earth, Jordan Kell led the first human mission beyond the solar system. They discovered the ruins of an ancient alien civilization. But one alien AI survived, and it revealed to Jordan Kell that an explosion in the black hole at the heart of the Milky Way galaxy has created a wave of deadly radiation, expanding out from the core toward Earth. Unless the human race acts to save itself, all life on Earth will be wiped out...", '9780765379504', authors[1], [genres[1],], callback);
            },
            function(callback) {
                bookCreate('Test Book 1', 'Summary of test book 1', 'ISBN111111', authors[4], [genres[0],genres[1]], callback);
            },
            function(callback) {
                bookCreate('Test Book 2', 'Summary of test book 2', 'ISBN222222', authors[4], false, callback)
            }
        ],
        // optional callback
        cb);
}


function createBookInstances(cb) {
    async.parallel([
            function(callback) {
                bookInstanceCreate(books[0], 'London Gollancz, 2014.', false, 'Available', callback)
            },
            function(callback) {
                bookInstanceCreate(books[1], ' Gollancz, 2011.', false, 'Loaned', callback)
            },
            function(callback) {
                bookInstanceCreate(books[2], ' Gollancz, 2015.', false, false, callback)
            },
            function(callback) {
                bookInstanceCreate(books[3], 'New York Tom Doherty Associates, 2016.', false, 'Available', callback)
            },
            function(callback) {
                bookInstanceCreate(books[3], 'New York Tom Doherty Associates, 2016.', false, 'Available', callback)
            },
            function(callback) {
                bookInstanceCreate(books[3], 'New York Tom Doherty Associates, 2016.', false, 'Available', callback)
            },
            function(callback) {
                bookInstanceCreate(books[4], 'New York, NY Tom Doherty Associates, LLC, 2015.', false, 'Available', callback)
            },
            function(callback) {
                bookInstanceCreate(books[4], 'New York, NY Tom Doherty Associates, LLC, 2015.', false, 'Maintenance', callback)
            },
            function(callback) {
                bookInstanceCreate(books[4], 'New York, NY Tom Doherty Associates, LLC, 2015.', false, 'Loaned', callback)
            },
            function(callback) {
                bookInstanceCreate(books[0], 'Imprint XXX2', false, false, callback)
            },
            function(callback) {
                bookInstanceCreate(books[1], 'Imprint XXX3', false, false, callback)
            }
        ],
        // Optional callback
        cb);
}



async.series([
        createGenreAuthors,
        createBooks,
        createBookInstances
    ],
// Optional callback
    function(err, results) {
        if (err) {
            console.log('FINAL ERR: '+err);
        }
        else {
            console.log('BOOKInstances: '+bookinstances);

        }
        // All done, disconnect from database
        mongoose.connection.close();
    });
```

How would I be able to solve this error as I after hours of trying to find a solution still doesn't find one.

Thx for helping

Comment: That's a lot of code to process. Can you reduce it to the __relevant__ part?

Comment: solved the problem, in one of my models schemas I had a fault thx for helping

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017/myapp', **{useNewUrlParser: true}**);
```

From official docs:

> useNewUrlParser - The underlying MongoDB driver has deprecated their
>   current connection string parser. Because this is a major change, they
>   added the useNewUrlParser flag to allow users to fall back to the old
>   parser if they find a bug in the new parser. You should set
>   useNewUrlParser: true unless that prevents you from connecting. Note
>   that if you specify useNewUrlParser: true, you must specify a port in
>   your connection string, like mongodb://localhost:27017/dbname. The new
>   url parser does not support connection strings that do not have a
>   port, like mongodb://localhost/dbname.

Comment: this solved the parser warning however I am still getting the
ValidationError: genre: Path genre is required. error